# It shows me an error when i try to open the google sheet ... Error like StopIteration and gspread.exceptions.SpreadsheetNotFound

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-sheets-api

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("creds.json", scope)

client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open("doc_name").sheet1 # Open the spreadhseet
```

When i run this code i get the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 120, in open
properties = finditem(
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gspread/utils.py", line 88, in finditem
return next((item for item in seq if func(item)))

StopIteration

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/samar/PycharmProjects/Automation/sheets.py", line 9, in 
sheet = client.open("Covid Data 2020-21").sheet1 # Open the spreadhseet
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 130, in open

```
raise SpreadsheetNotFound
```

gspread.exceptions.SpreadsheetNotFound

Answer (score 0):

**The error you are receiving seems to indicate that the spreadsheet with the "doc_name" name you have supplied does not exist.**

To retrieve a specific sheet from a specific spreadsheet, I suggest you supply the correct name or make the following change to your code:

```
spread_sheet = client.open_by_key('SPREADSHEET_ID') 
work_sheet = spread_sheet.worksheet('SHEET_NAME')
```

#### Reference

- [Gspread usage](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v4.0.1/user-guide.html#opening-a-spreadsheet).